# Acoustic wave vector and acoustic impedance

Tags: waves, acoustics

I'm working on Perfectly Matched Layer simulation, and I got this question.

As far as I know, generally, acoustic phase velocity is 
$$
v=\frac{\omega}{k}=\sqrt{\frac{C}{\rho}}
$$
where $\omega$ is angular frequency, $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is wavevector, C is Elastic constant, $\rho$ is density of medium.

However, in the "Parameter Extraction and Support-Loss in MEMS Resonators",

http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7953

the acoustic wavevector is [eq. 19]

$$
k=\frac{\omega\rho}{Z}
$$

where Z is acoustic impedance of medium, and

$$
Z_{compress}=\sqrt{\frac{\rho E (1-\nu)}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}}
$$
$$
Z_{shear}=\sqrt{\frac{\rho E }{2(1+\nu)}}
$$

Why is this different??

Is there any textbook which explains below equation (eq. 19)?

Comment: The details for wave motion in elastic solids are usually spelled out in books on continuum mechanics. For a very brief intro to elasticity in this case see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law#Tensor_expression_of_Hooke.27s_law

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference.
As the acoustic impedance of the medium is defined as 
$ Z=\rho v $, the first part of eq 19 is just 
$k=\frac{\omega}{v} $ with $v=\frac{Z}{\rho} $

The formulas for acoustic impedance result from the definition, replacing the speed with formulas expressing the speed of sound in a solid medium (longitudinal and transverse waves). 
The formula $ v= \sqrt{\frac{C}{\rho}} $ is valid for longitudinal waves propagating in a rod, when C is the Young's modulus.